# Comparing arguments passed in the terminal through char *argv[] in main

Tags: c++

I've been having trouble with the terminal, but I was wondering if something like this is legal:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if(argv[3] = "today")
    {
        //do something
    }
}
```

Otherwise, can I compare them using c-strings?

Comment: Is that supposed to be `=`?  Or `==`?  It's wrong either way, but you will have different results with each one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, that's not legal syntactically or logically.

You need to use [`strcmp`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcmp).

```
if (argc >= 4 && strcmp(argv[3], "today") == 0) {
    //matched
}
```

(Or, as Dietmar Kühl suggested, you could use std::string and much simplify your coding life.)

Comment: If you don't know that `argc` is 4 or more, that first comparison would be needed even with the C++ approach. If `argc` is 3, `argv[3]` will be a null pointer and the naive C++ approach will croak. Ff `argc` is less than 2, accessing `argv[3]` is undefined behavior.

Comment: @DavidHammen I never said it wasn't required?

Comment: I know you didn't. You did it the right way. None of the other answers, including mine, address the fact that `argv[3]` might be a null pointer or undefined. +1 for being a good paranoid programmer and testing whether it is valid to perform that comparison using `argv[3]`.

Answer (score 2):

The program arguments are just pointers to `char` arrays. You are comparing pointers rather than the string content. The easiest way is to compare the arguments using `std::string`, e.g.:

```
if (argv[3] == std::string("today")) {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    std::vector<std::string> arguments(argv, argv + argc);
    if (arguments[3] == "today")
    {
        //do something
    }
}
```

Comment: Yep, that's what I usually do when I'm writing a serious program that uses the command line arguments.

Answer (score 0):

`char* or arrays` can't be compared with `=` operator. You need to use `strcmp()` function

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if(strcmp(argv[3], "today") == 0)
    {
        //do something
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That will always return false. You are comparing two addresses, not two strings. What you want to do is to compare the contents of those addresses, or compare strings themselves.

In C the preferred approach is to use the function `strcmp`:

```
if (strcmp(argv[3], "today") == 0) {
   // Do something
}
```

In C++, use strings:

```
if (std::string("today") == argv[3]) {
   // Do something
}
```